# Multiple devices sending different messages to the same IoT hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

Say I have 30 devices installed in a plant. Each device is monitoring something different and sending messages to the same IoT Hub. Since an instance of Stream Analytics can only execute a single query, would I need 30 instances of SA running, each one processing the messages coming from a specific device? Or, I suppose I could have 30 IoT Hubs created. Neither of these alternatives seem particular attractive. How is a use case like this normally handled?

Comment: You _can_ have multiple queries in one Stream Analytics job; just put them into the query window one after the other.

Comment: This answer solves the problem correctly IMO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50339654/how-to-handle-two-iot-hub-devices-in-stream-analytics-job