# How to handle two "Iot hub" devices in "stream analytics job"?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I am using "stream analytics jobs" to visualize the data that comes from two different devices of an "iot hub", the device1 and the device2; the device1 sends the following message:

```
{"messageId": 5576, "deviceId": "Raspberry Pi Web", "rpm": 22.80972122577826, "torque": 72.65678451219686}
```

The device2 sends the following message:

```
{"messageId": 1272, "deviceId": "Raspberry Pi Web Client", "temperature": 23.815921380797004, "humidity": 78.7491052866882}
```

The messages are sent at the same time and when I want to visualize the data in power bi, I only see the keys of one of the messages, **messageId, temperature, humidity, PartitionId**. these keys belong to the message sent by the device2; but the **messageId, rpm, torque, PartitionId** keys that correspond to device1 do not appear.

The query I am using in the stream analytics job is the following:

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    output
FROM
    input
```

My devices are simulated devices that I use and configure from the following link: https://azure-samples.github.io/raspberry-pi-web-simulator/#Getstarted

How can I see messages from two different devices in the same iot hub with stream analytics job?

Note: I am using F1 level in "IoT Hub"

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerBI, one dataset represents a single source of data and has to be in a format:

> There are literally hundreds of different data sources you can use
>   with Power BI. But regardless of where you get your data from, that
>   data has to be in a format the Power BI service can use to create
>   reports and dashboards.

Reference: [dataset concept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-basic-concepts#datasets) and [data source for Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-get-data#what-if-my-data-comes-from-a-different-source).

For your issue you can route two devices events to two Power BI dataset.(two outputs in ASA job).

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    *
INOT
    powerbi
FROM
    iothubevents
WHERE
    deviceId = 'Raspberry Pi Web'


SELECT
    *
INOT
    powerbidevice2
FROM
    iothubevents
WHERE
    deviceId = 'Raspberry Pi Web Client'
```

See these snapshots:
In stream analytics job:

[image]

[image]

In Power BI:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @rita, thanks for answering, The example you showed works. I appreciate your help.